# TYPO3 list module: custom records not showing

Tags: typo3

I am using TYPO3 7.6.11.
I wrote an provider extension to add some ts-code, templates, and viewhelpers.
After that, I wanted to add a custom data record (to use in the Backend).

I added the table in the ext_tables.sql.
I have a TCA-config under /[extension]/Configuration/TCA/tablename.php

I added

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tablename');
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToInsertRecords('tablename');
```

to my ext_tables.php

Did I miss something?

I get a new record type under "System Records" in the List Module. I can add such an record, and the TCA-config seems to work fine for the record form.

But after saving, I have no record in the list view. The DB is looking fine. The record is saved correctly in my new table. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Edit:
crtl:

```
'ctrl' => array (
    'title' =>       'LLL:EXT:svkcore/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:records.title',
    'label' => 'title',
    'label_alt' => '',
    'label_alt_force' => TRUE,
    'default_sortby' => 'ORDER BY datetime DESC',
    'prependAtCopy' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.php:LGL.prependAtCopy',
    'versioningWS' => TRUE,
    'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,
    'origUid' => 't3_origuid',
    'shadowColumnsForNewPlaceholders' => 'sys_language_uid,l18n_parent,starttime,endtime,fe_group',

    'dividers2tabs' => TRUE,
    'useColumnsForDefaultValues' => 'type',
    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l18n_parent',
    'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l18n_diffsource',
    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
    'crdate' => 'crdate',
    'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
    'delete' => 'deleted',
    'type' => 'type',
    'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
    'editlock' => 'editlock',
    'enablecolumns' => array (
        'disabled' => 'hidden',
        'starttime' => 'starttime',
        'endtime' => 'endtime',
        'fe_group' => 'fe_group',
    ),
    'typeicon_column' => 'type',
    'typeicons' => array (
        '1' => 'EXT:svkcore/res/gfx/svkcore_inturl.gif',
        '2' => 'EXT:svkcore/res/gfx/svkcore_exturl.gif',
    ),
    'thumbnail' => 'image',
    'iconfile' => 'EXT:svkcore/res/gfx/ext_icon.gif',
    'searchFields' => 'uid,title,short,bodytext'),
'interface' => Array (
    'showRecordFieldList' => 'title,hidden,datetime_start,starttime,archivedate,category,short,image,record_files'
),
```

Comment: Is the pid of the record also saved correctly?

Comment: Yes the pid in the DB is correct

Comment: Don't you have a `'hideTable' => true,` in `ctrl` section of TCA definition of your table?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the TCA configuration. If you can create a new record, save it and see it in the database but not in TYPO3 then it seems like you have a TCA configuration issue - it could be hideTable in the CTRL section as Victor points out

Comment: I added the crtl part. I generally adopted the configuration from tt_news.

Comment: Do you have any SQL issues? Perhaps TYPO3 tries to fetch the records with invalid SQL due to miss configured TCA. It will not show the records in that case.

Perhaps one of the following fields is missing in your database?
- fe_group
- endtime
- sys_language_uid
- l18n_diffsource
- l18n_parent
- t3_origuid
- datetime

Answer (score 1):

Since Typo3 7 it is possible to mask the list-view. This is configured via PageTSConfig, have a look at your info-Module (select the correct page in the page tree) and check the TSConfig there.

The configuration can be found in the following path:

```
mod.web_list.allowedNewTables
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in ext_tables.php if you have everything needed for your new table : Typoscript inclusion, language file, exemple :

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'My TS configuration');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('tx_myext_domain_model_mytable', 'EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_tx_myext_domain_model_mytable.xlf');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_myext_domain_model_mytable');
```

Are you sure the new records are stored in the current page : have a look at the TS "**persistence.storagePid**".
You can check in the database wich pid is used for your new records.

Regards,
Florian

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
First: I thought the TCAdescr part is not mandatory. I added it now, but the problem still exists.

When i read your answer i saw this: "tx_myext_domain_model_mytable"
Is this just the naming convention, or do i have to create a domain/model for my table?

Comment: I have a typoscript inclusion, but nothing inside for my record-table. Do i have to add some typoscript for the table?

do i have to set persistence.storagePid? I just wanted to create the records in the current folder in the backend.

Comment: TypoScript is "only" for the frontend (can be used in custom backend modules) and persistence.storagePid is a ExtBase configuration in TypoScript and also "only" frontend. The addLLrefForTCAdescr is optional.